# How to access Azure Devops API from yaml pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

Currently I am trying to do a simple query to retrieve related work items for the triggering build of the pipeline. I am getting unauthorized response and have no idea where to proceed.

```
- bash: |    url="https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProj/_apis/build/builds/$(resources.pipeline.build.runID)/workitems"
    response=$(curl $url -H 'Authorization: Bearer $SYSTEMACCESSTOKEN')
    echo $response
  env:
    SYSTEMACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Why is the System.AccessToken not being accepted as a valid token?

The URL i echo earlier is working and returns work items when accessed through the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token should be Base64 encoded if used in header

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#assemble-the-request

Comment: Hi, just a bit of info here, it is true that you need to Base64 encode a Personal Access Token (PAT) when supplying the Authorization header with using a "Basic" token.  However, the built in System.AccessToken variable is actually an OAuth token and is passed using Bearer.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services for details about the System.AccessToken where it is described as an OAuth token.

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting the authorization header you need to use double quotes ("") so that the `$SYSTEMACCESSTOKEN` variable is interpolated with the actual value.  When you use single quotes you are setting the Bearer token to the string literal `$SYSTEMACCESSTOKEN`.

Also, it looks like you are referencing a build as a resource in the pipeline.  Please note that you may encounter permissions issues if the build exists in a different project unless you disable the `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` in the Project Settings --> Pipelines --> Settings section (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) article for more information).

As a simple test (no pipeline resource) I was able to get a response using the following task code:

```
- bash: |
    response=$(curl -H "authorization: Bearer $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" -H 'accept: */*' -H 'api-version: 7.1-preview' -H 'excludeUrls: true' -H 'ContentType: application/json' "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/workitems")
    echo $response
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```